# Sorting an ArrayAdapter - ignoring case

Tags: android, sorting, android-arrayadapter, case-insensitive

I am using the following code to sort an ArrayAdapter alphabetically:

```
adapter.sort(new Comparator<String>() {
    public int compare(String object1, String object2) {
        return object2.compareTo(object1);
    };
});
```

Trouble is, it arranges all the Uppercase entries before the lowercase entries.

How do I force it to ignore case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [String.compareToIgnoreCase()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#compareToIgnoreCase%28java.lang.String%29)

```
return object2.compareToIgnoreCase(object1);
```

Or [String.toLowerCase()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#toLowerCase%28%29) method:

```
return object2.toLowerCase().compareTo(object1.toLowerCase());
```

Comment: [`String#compareToIgnoreCase(String)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#compareToIgnoreCase%28java.lang.String%29) is safer if the string is localized text. E.g. in turkish `"I".toLowerCase()` = `ı` and not `i`.

Comment: Interesting, so is the upper case of `i` `I`?

Comment: `i` -> `İ` so `jim` and `JIM` won't be equals (I think) if the (device) locale is turkish even with `String#compareToIgnoreCase()`. If you compare strings that are not localized text you can use `toLowerCase(Locale.US)` since that forces `i` <> `I` etc